# Searching the Records on basis of Date

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

Hi I need to find the records on the basis of Billed date, Now when the user hits the Url
"/bills/due/25-11-2020" the search would fetch me all records on date 25 Nov 2020

```
public interface BillsRepository extends JpaRepository<Bills, Long> {

 @Query(value = "Select Bills.billedDate,Bills.billNo, Bills.billedTo from Bills where Bills.billedDate is like %?1%", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Bills> findByDate(@Param("date") Date date);
}
```

and my service Method

```
    @Override
    public List<Bills> getbillsByDate(Date date) throws ParseException {
        List<Bills> billsbydate = billRepo.findByDate(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd").parse(date.toString()));

        return billsbydate;
    }
```

Whenever I am hitting the Url from my Controller method

```
@GetMapping("bills/due/{date}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Bills>> getByDate(@PathVariable("date") Date date) throws ParseException {
        List<Bills> billsByDate = billService.getbillsByDate(date);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(billsByDate);
    }
```

it throws an exception

```
2021-11-16 08:18:58.396  WARN 29141 --- [nio-9070-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable java.util.Date] for value '15-11-2021'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException]
```

Any am Newbie to Spring date JPA, So any help would be appreciated
Thnks

Answer (score 0):

As a dirty solution, In your controller try this.

Instead of `@PathVariable("date") Date date` use `@PathVariable("date") String date` and then convert the `String date` to `Date date` - the same way you are doing in your service.

OR

Follow this:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-date-parameters

This URL has your outlined the exact error you are facing.